# Convert certain string to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

How can I convert strings of following formats to DateTime in C#:

1. May 17, 4:52PM GMT+01:00
2. May 17, 3:57PM EDT

Does .NET have support for converting these strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime.Parse()` won't recognize either of those formats. However, you can specify custom formats if you use [ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss) instead.  Information on how to specify DateTime format strings is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

For example, the format string for the first format would be `"MMMM dd, h:mmtt 'GMT'zzz"`.

There's no way to capture non-numeric time zone designations with DateTime format strings, so the second format is a bit trickier.  I'd probably just check for that situation ahead of time.  When it does, you might be able to just chop the last 3 letters off the end and use a lookup table to convert them into GMT offsets to apply to the DateTime you get from parsing the first portion of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `DateTime.Parse` won't understand those timezones. The three letter abbreviations are not a good way to specify a timezone because there are many ambiguous abbreviations. For example "CST" can mean either "Central Standard Time" or "China Standard Time".

Unless you know which country the timezone is from (and I'm guessing that you don't), you are probably out of luck.

Comment: Thanks. DateTime.Parse throws exception because it doesn't understand the format. Unfortunately I have no control over the format as I am getting the data from external source...

Comment: @Emon: Yes, but I think the main problem is that what you are trying to do is probably impossible. Or at least, you will need to provide more information (such as the country from which the data comes) in order to distinguish the ambiguous cases.

Comment: I only need to deal with GMT and EST. I will try out  DateTime.ParseExact(), let see if that helps...

Comment: "I only need to deal with GMT and EST"... err... and EDT, right? That was your example.

Comment: @Emon: Also your input data doesn't seem to include the year. What should happen if you get a timestamp that just says "January"? Is that January 2012 or 2013? And what if it says November?

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToDateTime(yourDateTimeString);`

[MSDN information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try the DateTime Parse method:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx